# nothing provides /bin/env needed by foo

Tags: yocto, openembedded

I am building a new recipe which contains python.

when doing bitbake foo, it pass without problem.

when building overall image, it shows this error:

```
nothing provides /bin/env needed by foo
```

Comment: If you change the shebang of the python file from '/bin/env python' to the real path (e.g. /usr/bin/python', will it still fail?

Comment: after changed /bin/env to /usr/bin/env, it pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the shebang of the python file from '/bin/env python' to the real path (e.g. /usr/bin/python'.